# OS X application to burn a .mov to a DVD?

Tags: osx, optical-media

The other day I found it necessary to burn an MOV to a DVD. Sounds simple, right? No. I didn't want any special effects, I just wanted an MOV on a DVD. Eventually, I just used iDVD and found a hack to remove all the menus and chrome.

The app must:

- Not apply any styling, menus, or other things to the movie (or at least have the option not to)
- Intake an MOV and burn it to a DVD
- Burn the MOV onto the DVD in a way that is playable by a standard DVD player; I don't want to just put the MOV file itself onto the disk.

Is there a dedicated OS X app for this?

Comment: http://www.ffmpegx.com/ *could* help with that, as it supports converting .mov as input format and DVD as output format. Disk Utility.app can burn image to DVD.

Answer (score 2):

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2211/10687

I found this software via the above answer on this site.

I do know that it can:

- Handle .MOV files that is what I needed (I did use the Windows version of the software thought)
- I was also able to play the disc on my regular DVD player.

I am not sure at this time if it can:

- Complete remove all the menus etc.

http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/